# How to implement a UI widget that collapses on scroll, in React Native?

Tags: react-native

The standard iOS weather app has a special scrolling UI behavior:

[image]

There are various parts in the UI: the upper part (with the big 20), the middle (horizontal) bar, the lower part with the weekdays and the footer.

When you scroll up,

- The upper part does not scroll, but it collapses until it has a certain minimum height, then it stays there "stickyly".
- The middle bar scrolls up until the upper part does not collapse anymore, then it stays there "stickily".
- The lower part (which has more height than fits onto the screen) scrolls up without any special behavior.
- The footer is fixed, and overlaps the lower part.

[image]

**How can I implement something similar in React Native?** I don't need all the details, just an idea of how the upper part could be realized, i.e. a component that collapses while scrolling, until it stays fixed at the top, with a minimum height.

Of course, I'd prefer a pure RN solution, which works both on iOS and Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an example [here](https://medium.com/@habibridho/implementing-collapsing-toolbar-using-react-native-4a84e1718f11).

Only the part which really scrolls is inside a `ScrollView`, the collapsing part is not. Then you hook up on the `ScrollView.onScroll` event and connect the `contentOffset` property via `Animated.event` and `Animated.interpolate` to the height of the header:

```
const HEADER_EXPANDED_HEIGHT = 300
const HEADER_COLLAPSED_HEIGHT = 60
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      scrollY: new Animated.Value(0)
    }
  }
  render() {
    const headerHeight = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, HEADER_EXPANDED_HEIGHT-HEADER_COLLAPSED_HEIGHT],
      outputRange: [HEADER_EXPANDED_HEIGHT, HEADER_COLLAPSED_HEIGHT],
      extrapolate: 'clamp'
    })
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Animated.View style={{height: headerHeight}}/>
          <ScrollView
            contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollContainer}
            onScroll={Animated.event(
              [{ nativeEvent: {
                   contentOffset: {
                     y: this.state.scrollY
                   }
                 }
              }])}
            scrollEventThrottle={16}>
            ...
          </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```